# Does AMD support x2APIC?

Tags: x86, cpu, osdev, amd-processor, apic

I'm a learner of OS, and trying to write a kernel.

I googled for "AMD x2APIC" and found out some of the information about EPYC 7002 series seems like to support it.

But I cannot find the relative documentation.

So I would like to ask if the recent AMD processors support it, and if yes, where I can find documentation.

Comment: https://sudonull.com/post/8076-Interrupts-from-external-devices-in-the-x86-system-Part-1-The-evolution-of-interrupt-controllers looks relevant, and links an Intel doc: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/specification-update/64-architecture-x2apic-specification.pdf.  If AMD's implementation is compatible with Intel, just follow Intel's x2APIC spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the same as in Intel's CPUs.
You use `cpuid` (`CPUID_Fn00000001_ECX`) to check for it

[image: CPUID_Fn00000001_ECX]

and the `Core::X86::Msr::APIC_BAR` MSR to enable it:

[image: Core::X86::Msr::APIC_BAR]

Just like you would with Intel's CPUs.

---

The x2APIC specification is [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-architecture-x2apic-specification).

Comment: So AMD follows intel, that's why they do not have their own doc??

Comment: @Shore x2APIC is an open specification, it was written by Intel but it's not tied to Intel's CPUs. AMD adopted it because it is not interested in developing its own xAPIC alternative. But, for one thing, the 64-bit extension was written by AMD and Intel followed. It's not good to create too many different architectures.